# Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'str_replace(array('.', ',', "'", ' '), '', '\1') . '.\4'', to be a valid callback

Tags: php

Sorry guys i'm not a programmer but i like to play and add and modify programming i'm having a problem ever since i upgraded from php 5 to 7.2 some of my codes are not working correctly like this one below.

```
function floatvalue($value)
{
    return floatval(preg_replace_callback('#^([-]*[0-9\.,\' ]+?)((\.|,){1}([0-9-]{1,2}))*$#e', "str_replace(array('.', ',', \"'\", ' '), '', '\\1') . '.\\4'", $value));
}
if (!function_exists('mb_ucfirst') && function_exists('mb_substr')) {
    function mb_ucfirst($string)
    {
        $string = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($string, 0, 1)) . mb_substr($string, 1);
        return $string;
    }
}
```

The error i get is

```
Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'str_replace(array('.', ',', "'", ' '), '', '\1') . '.\4'', to be a valid callback in /var/www...
```

i've been searching i'm not understanding what to do exactly. Anyone can help on this ? thanks!

Comment: Enclosing something in quotes doesn't make it callable. Have a look at the examples in the [documentation](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

Comment: It means that for preg_replace_callback is expecting a callback function for the 2nd parameter (argument), but something else was given. In your case is a string (between double quotes) of a function, but for php it's just a string. To see how to actually pass in a callback check the example given in docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php Also be aware that your code looks kind of advanced if you are that of a newcomer to programming and understanding it may require some effort investment on learning a few base concepts as datatypes and callbacks.

Comment: The `/e` flag is obsolete. So it looks like that's why you tried to migrate to `preg_replace_callback` already. It's somewhat too convoluted to tell what this code was meant to extract; so maybe rewrite it from scratch. The whole `str_replace` seems somewhat redundant. Though you might just split it up into two lines, rather than try to use it as a callback.

Comment: See also: [Replace preg\_replace() e modifier with preg\_replace\_callback](//stackoverflow.com/q/15454220)